# Apex Oracle interactive grid checkbox always visible

Tags: jquery, oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with a checkbox column. I want to show always the checkbox because It appear only when I click on the cell.

[image: there isn't the checkbox]
[image: when i click on cell the checkbox appear]

Can someone help Me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the underlying query?

Comment: The underlying query isn't necessary - this is a pure javascript/jQuery problem, nothing to do with what data is being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plug-in that does the trick:
https://github.com/rafael-trevisan/apex-plugin-ig_simple_checkbox

However it has a couple of outstanding issues:

- You can't use NULL as a value - you need to specify both a checked and unchecked value (Y and N or 1 and 0 for example)
- The checkboxes are displayed all the time but the user still has to click into the cell to selected it and then click the checkbox in order to check/uncheck it.

It should be possible to remedy that last one with a bit of jQuery. I'll see what I can do and update this answer if I get anywhere with it.